# Android/Admob: Can I set a list of testing devices in the Layout XML for the AdView?

Tags: android, admob

So, I currently have an AdView in my layout like this:

```
  <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="false"/>
```

and that works just fine. However, I have to get the AdView in the source code in order to pass it a request for the Emulator and my personal phone to be TestingDevices and not receive real ads. Is there a way I can list those in the XML directly? or even force the AdView to ONLY show test ads, so that I don't have to have that chunk of code and can set the AdView to loadAdOnCreate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, add this to the xml:

```
ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
```

I found it here: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/banner_xml

Comment: Any chance of an example please? I presume TEST_DEVICE_ID is just a placeholder for the real device ID. Is TEST_EMULATOR a magic constant though or a placeholder for something else?

Comment: @Caltor No this is the line that you need to add. Both TEST_EMULATOR AND TEST_DEVICE_ID are constant and not placeholders. You can see more info right [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/additional-controls#android-test)

Comment: I'm with you on TEST_EMULATOR but the code example at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#android-addtestdevice seems to imply device id should be a string literal.